# What error estimates is used for 5x2 cv paired t-test?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, cross-validation

I am performing a 5x2 cv paired t-test. I have read most of the paper "Evaluating the Replicability of Significance Tests for Comparing Learning Algorithms" by Remco R. Bouckaert and Eibe Frank up to the 5x2 cv test.

In that test they only mention the metrics $p_A$ and $p_B$ as "error estimates" and now I am wondering what this entails. Since the test is supposed to prove a hypothesis based on some metrics of classification between two models, am I free to use any performance metric as a measurement?

I have scoured the internet for an answer to this question and even though I have not found any conclusive evidence, intuitionally I find it to be so. I can test my hypothesis $H_o: M_1 = M_2 $ against any performance metric.